# Using recursive properties ASP.NET / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, recursion

I'm looking for a way to take a generic result set and turn it into a tree structure with ASP.NET MVC using jQuery Dyantree. I've got a test class like:

```
public class GenericResults
{
    public string ClaimId { get; set; }
    public string DrugName { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    //simulates database call, this could be any type of result set
    public static List<GenericResults> MockDatabaseCall()
    {
        return new List<GenericResults>()
        {
            new GenericResults { ClaimId = "abc", DrugName="Drug 1",  PatientId=1 },
            new GenericResults { ClaimId = "bcd", DrugName="Drug 2",  PatientId=1 },
            new GenericResults { ClaimId = "def", DrugName="Drug 3",  PatientId=1 },
            new GenericResults { ClaimId = "fgi", DrugName="Drug 4",  PatientId=1 },
            new GenericResults { ClaimId = "ijk", DrugName="Drug 5",  PatientId=2 },
            new GenericResults { ClaimId = "klm", DrugName="Drug 6",  PatientId=2 },
            new GenericResults { ClaimId = "mno", DrugName="Drug 7",  PatientId=2 },
            new GenericResults { ClaimId = "pqr", DrugName="Drug 8",  PatientId=2 },
            new GenericResults { ClaimId = "qrs", DrugName="Drug 9",  PatientId=2 },
            new GenericResults { ClaimId = "stu", DrugName="Drug 10", PatientId=2 },
        };
    }
}
```

The structure the data needs to be in for Dynatree is like:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public List<TreeView> Children { get; set; }
public bool IsFolder
{
    get
    {
        return this.Children.Count > 0;
    }
}
```

In this example, we really don't need the `ClaimId` property, but I want to reuse stored procedures I've already written to feed to the trees so I wanted to include it. I need what has been grouped on to become its own `TreeView` object, and the `Children` property to be all the records that have the value of what was grouped on.  So far the `MockDatabaseCallMethod`, if I grouped on `PatientId` I would need two  `TreeView` objects: one for each unique PatientId.  I would like to be able to do this recursively, but not sure how because some items will be leaves (no children) and that's fine.  Here's my attempt:

```
public class TreeView
{
    public string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<TreeView> Children { get; set; }

    public bool IsFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Children.Count > 0;
        }
    }

    //made void for the time being to limit compilation errors
    public static void ListToTree(string displayName,string groupedOn)
    {
        //seed data
        List<GenericResults> results = GenericResults.MockDatabaseCall();

        //"group" on the property passed by the user
        var query = results.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(groupedOn).GetValue(x,null)).Distinct();

        foreach (var i in query)
        {
            var treeView = new TreeView();
            treeView.Title = displayName;

            //iterate over results, if object has the property value of what's currently being iterated over
            //create a new TreeView object for it
            treeView.Children = results.Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(groupedOn).GetValue(x, null) == i)
                                       .Select(n => new TreeView
                                                    {
                                                        Title = displayName,
                                                        Children = x <--no idea what to do here
                                                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like a `ToTree` extension method, but at first I'd like to get some pointers on this.  Thanks :)

Comment: It sounds like your `TreeView` will never have more than two levels - one level for the group value and the next level for all items that have the "current" value? If so, a recursive method is overkill. Just use a simple `results.GroupBy(...)` or similar to separate the items into groups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but if I did I would suggest the following solution:

-) In `TreeView` change the property `public List<TreeView> Children { get; set; }` to `public IEnumerable<GenericResults> Children { get; set; }`.

-) Replace your `void ListToTree(string displayName` method with the following one:

```
public static List<TreeView> ListToTree(string displayName, string groupedOn)
{
    //seed data
    List<GenericResults> results = GenericResults.MockDatabaseCall();

    List<TreeView> trees = new List<TreeView>();

    //"group" on the property passed by the user
    var query = results.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(groupedOn).GetValue(x, null)).Distinct();

    foreach (int i in query)
    {
        var treeView = new TreeView();
        treeView.Title = displayName;
        treeView.Children = results.Where(x => ((int)x.GetType().GetProperty(groupedOn).GetValue(x, null)) == i);

        trees.Add(treeView);
    }

    return trees;
}
```

I'm not sure however, if I understood you correctly ;-)

Comment: Hi, Markus.  I tried your code and I got an error on the `results.Where...` line can't convert IEnumerable<GenericResult> to List<TreeView>.

Comment: Yes because you need to change the property as well (see text above at the beginning)